# C# Generic Method Ambiguity

Tags: c#, interface

I need to use generic methods and non-generic methods in the same interface.

```
public interface IBRClientActions<T>
    where T : class 
{
    T add(T element);
    Hashtable add(Hashtable hashtable);

    void update(T element);
    void update(Hashtable hashtable);
}
```

After I implement this interface in other interface with many type

```
public interface IBRClientActions : IBRClientActions<AdresseClient>,
                                    IBRClientActions<Role>,
                                    IBRClientActions<LienClient>
{
    ...
}
```

in my final class I need something like that

```
public class FinalClass : IBRClientActions
{
    AdresseClient add(AdresseClient element) { ... }
    Hashtable add**<AdresseClient>**(Hashtable hashtable) { ... }
    ....
}
```

But `Hashtable add<AdresseClient>(Hashtable hashtable) { ... }`  is not possible
Actually I have ambiguous reference in methods with Hashtable.

How can I have an add method with Hashtable for each type?

---

Edit 1

Explicit interface implementation

Yes that is a possibility but with this solution I need to cast my class each time

```
Hashtable htRole = new Hashtable();
FinalClass myClass = new FinalClass();

/* not correct, ambiguity */
myClass.add(htRole);

/* correct, no ambiguity but heavy writing (sorry for my bad english) */
((IBRClientActions<Role>)myClass).add(htRole);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I need to use generic methods and non-generic methods in the same interface.

I don't think that's the problem, really. I think the real problem is that you're implementing the same generic interface multiple times with different type arguments in the same class. Without that aspect, you wouldn't have a problem here.

You can use explicit interface implementation:

```
Hashtable IBRClientActions<Role>.add(Hashtable hashatable)
{
    ...
}
```

But this becomes ugly pretty quickly. I'd try to avoid doing this if possible. Try using composition instead of inheritance.

Also note:

- If this is `System.Collections.Hashtable`, you should probably be using `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<,>` if possible
- The method name `add` doesn't conform to .NET naming conventions